# Will a couple of guppy males be happy in my fish tank?

Tags: aquarium, fish, freshwater, community-aquarium, guppies

Will a couple of guppy males be happy in a community tank without guppy females? Will they harrass for example platy females or will they mind their own business?

The tank is a Juwel Vision 450 LED with the following inhabitants:

- ~20 Platy (mixed sexes)
- 5 Ancistrus sp (mixed sexes)
- 10 Five banded barbs
- 10 Rummy nose tetras
- 10 Panda corydoras

Comment: Wow, this is an almost 120gallon tank! I just checked it out online- from what I can tell, looks like you have brilliant set up

Comment: When I separated my males from females  (removed females from mixed tank) and I ended up with mixed breed babies. I had two of my Balloon mollies give birth to mixed breeds (fancy male guppy cross) and only a few made it, sad bc I'm not used to fish loss...but even with female guppies being put back in, my males still harass the female mollies. I'm commenting, not answering bc I'm unsure if these are typical results.

Comment: I'm not sure there is anything like 'typical results' when it comes to keeping fish. I've had a couple  male guppies  in a small tank (no other fish) without any problems. But I've also read stories where they would fight each other... But since it's such a big tank, I think you can give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Given the size of your tank, if you provide plenty of cover, they'll be more inclined to avoid your barbs nipping their tails. There is definitely the possibility of them harrasing the Platy's due to them being from the livebearing 'family' so to speak. Again, with plenty of cover/hiding places, that behaviour can be reduced.